# How to perform some action when the Tab is selected in javafx?

Tags: javafx, fxml, scenebuilder

I have a Tab with "total" id and get it in a listener with switch:

```
 switch ((event.getSource().toString().substring(event.getSource().toString().indexOf("=")+1,event.getSource().toString().indexOf(",")))) {
        case "signin":
            changeScene(signin, "atmOperation");
            User user = new User();
            user.check();
            break;

        case "signout":
            changeScene(signout, "login");
            break;
        case "signup":
            changeScene(signup, "signup");
            break;
        case "back":
            changeScene(back, "atmOperation");
            break;
        case "exit":
            stage = (Stage) exit.getScene().getWindow();
            stage.close();
            break;
        case "total":
            System.out.print(total.isSelected());
            break;
```

And this is my layout fxml file:

```
<?import javafx.scene.control.Tab?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TabPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>

<Pane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="443.0" prefWidth="610.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.65" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.Controller">
   <children>
      <TabPane fx:id="tabPane" layoutY="37.0" nodeOrientation="RIGHT_TO_LEFT" onContextMenuRequested="#event" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="610.0" tabClosingPolicy="UNAVAILABLE">
        <tabs>
          <Tab fx:id="total" closable="false" text="x" onSelectionChanged="#event">
            <content>
              <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
            </content>
          </Tab>
          <Tab text="x">
            <content>
              <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
            </content>
          </Tab>
            <Tab text="y">
               <content>
                  <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
               </content>
            </Tab>
            <Tab text="y">
               <content>
                  <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
               </content>
            </Tab>
        </tabs>
      </TabPane>
   </children>
</Pane>
```

I want to handle programm if user click on tab with total id but i used onSelectionChanged that can not help me!
How i can handle it if user click on total id tab?

Comment: Do you want to perform some action when the Tab with fx:id `total` is selected? Or do you want that the Tab should be selected by default?

Comment: Thank you my friend ,I want to perform some action when the Tab with fx:id total is selected

Answer (score 4):

You can do that with either  the selectedItemProperty or selectedIndexProperty . Below is the solution using selectedItemProperty. The switch case is not needed.

```
// starts here
tabPane.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Tab>() { 
    @Override 
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Tab> observable, Tab oldTab, Tab newTab) {
        if(newTab.equals (total)) {            
            System.out.print(total.isSelected());
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `onSelectionChanged` for that, in your Controller `event` method, just check if the totalTab is selected or not, like below, please note that the name of the annotated tab must match the `fx:id` set in the fxml file, and the method name, in this case `event` must match the name `onSelectionChanged="#event"` in the fxml file.

```
  public class Controller {

      @FXML
      private Tab total;

      @FXML
      void event(Event ev) {
          if (total.isSelected()) {
              System.out.println("Tab is Selected");
              //Do stuff here
          }
      }
  }
```

or pure programmatically:

```
    total.setOnSelectionChanged(event -> {
        if (total.isSelected()) {
            System.out.println("Tab is Selected");
            //Do stuff here
        }
    });
```